# Achievements box lines looking weird

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, achievements-dialog

This is what I see on Stack Overflow:

[image]

And same exact achievement box on other sites, e.g. MSE:

[image]

Browser: Chrome 47.0.2526.106 under Windows 7, no extension, userscripts, or add-ons. No zoom (100%), screen resolution 1920x1080.

The second looks much better. Can the Stack Overflow achievements box design be fixed, or if on purpose, be changed  to match other sites?

Worth to mention, it looks OK here on MSO, the problem is only on the main Stack Overflow site.

Comment: Oddly I don't see this on any sites. do you have any user styling? Which browsers?

Comment: Not reproducible here. Windows 64 bit, Firefox 43.0.1 64 bit, several SE related user scripts.

Comment: The first screenshot looks smaller, is that browser window zoomed out a bit perhaps? If I zoom out I can repro this.

Comment: bah, forgot to do what I always tell others to do. Sorry guys, adding details now.

Comment: If you're not zoomed, why is the first image smaller? Even the fonts are smaller.

Comment: @David no idea, I always assumed SO is using different font sizes, ever since some design change few weeks (months?) ago

Comment: No, nothing changed for me recently, font changes are a pretty big deal on SO so I'm sure we'd have seen a hundred meta posts if that had happened! The first one is absolutely smaller than mine. I'm curious what font size you have there. What is the font size of the "ACHIEVEMENTS" word at the top? Mine is 15px.

Comment: @DavidG 15px too, CSS rule for `<h3>` tag.

Comment: That's definitely not 15px on screen, there must be something affecting you here. How does it look incognito or with a Chrome window with [no extensions](http://superuser.com/questions/254579/how-to-open-google-chrome-with-extensions-disabled-turned-off)?

Comment: *self slap* - Sorry @David and everyone, I'm so silly. I didn't notice Chrome can have different zoom for each site and **this zoom is then being stored, for good** - just noticed I somehow had it on 90% for http://stackoverflow.com/ only, probably changed it by mistake in the past and never noticed. Think it is worth an answer to prevent other silly mistakes like this?

Comment: Personally I'd delete the question and [move quietly away, slowly stepping backwards, pretending this never happened](http://i.imgur.com/7O2FM6I.gif)...

Comment: LOL @David - you convinced me. :-D

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I fell for something so simple and silly, that I now want to bury myself deep in the ground.

Chrome browser is smart enough to remember the zoom setting for each website you visit. Even if you close the browser, open again, browsing incognito - the zoom level will prevail.

I checked the zoom level on other sites (MSE, here on MSO when reporting) and also didn't notice this:

> [image]

See this small magnifying glass next to the Bookmark star? Turns out it means a custom zoom level is being used for the site you browse.

So what happened? At some point in the past, I changed the zoom level by mistake (random middle wheel scroll while CTRL is clicked for example), and never noticed. Setting zoom back to 100% "fixed" my issue.

Now go laugh at me, and don't let it happen to you! :D